# Im trying to create User Roles in MVC5. My context property is showing null i have no idea why

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

https://gyazo.com/0e64a4a003c33f117f114b914ccde492

As you can see in the picture above when i call the RegisterRole Action i got a Nullreference error. It's my first time working with ApplicationDbContext class.

Controller class:

```
 private ApplicationDbContext context;
```

Action Methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterRole()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
        ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(context.Users.ToList(), "UserName", "UserName");
        return View();
    }


    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterRole(RegisterViewModel model, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var userId = context.Users.Where(i => i.UserName == user.UserName).Select(s => s.Id);
        string updatedId = "";
        foreach (var i in userId)
        {
            updatedId = i.ToString();
        }
        await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(updatedId, model.Name);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Where is context defined? Have you initialized it before that action?

Comment: Yes, I assigned it in the account controller.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Teddy I've inserted the code.

Comment: How did you set value of context?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to add  public AccountController()
        {
            //
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

Comment: @Teddy Thank you, for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If context was not initialized, then it should be null.

You can inject it with controller construct method, or simply initialized with `context = new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString);`

connectionString could be settings in config file.